# Does Earth Science cover the universe?

Tags: support, scope

I am interested in science (particular how the universe works) and so I watch the Discovery Channel. Does this Stack Exchange site cover questions about the universe or does it only cover questions about Earth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Earth science only covers a subset of the universe.

For the earth, earth science covers processes from the planetary core to the extent of its atmosphere.  As the processes that occur on earth are shared by other planets, our scope also includes other planets.

The space between planets is not part of our scope.  Likewise physics that are unrelated to earth science processes is not part of our scope (e.g. quantum field theory belongs on physics.stackexchange.com, not here).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that this site did not cover the universe. Is there a SE website that does cover the universe or non-fiction science since the link you gave is in Swedish and not English.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper I have fixed the link.  `.se` was shorthand `.stackexchange.com`. The URL is http://physics.stackexchange.com.  Science and physics are spread across multiple sites.  We have sites for physics, chemistry, biology, astronomy, space exploration, math, and many others.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So things such as stars, Magnetars, commits, galaxies supernovas etc. belong on astronomy.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @aPyDeveloper yes.

Answer (score 4):

Another Stack Exchange site to consider is [Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) which is specifically about astronomy and astrophysics.  This site is in beta (like here) and has a group of astronomers there happy to answer questions (some of them are *fast*).